# number of rows in section, how to set this value after a parse query in the cell for row at index path function

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

So i need some help with controlling my code flow, i'm trying to make a list display cells that i query from my parse server, however i do not know the amount of cells until i make the query in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
//Query goes here {rowCount = queryResult.count}
```

I have tried to create a global variable that will take the object count, but have no success since i have to set the value to something beforehand, like this:

```
var rowcount = 0

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 



    return rowCount
}
```

Any good example on how to control this so that i get the right amount of rows from the query?

I did not find any similar question on Stack, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't query web service in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Please teach me the best practice for this, should i make a function for it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After you receive your row count call `tableView.reloadData()`
In your main thread.

Or like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


   //Query goes here {rowCount = queryResult.count}
tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: infinite loop. probably will crash or something.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with a small check: 

    if firstCall == true {
            tableView.reloadData()
                firstCall = false
                println("firstcall happened")
            }

Comment: @LucasGron the reason you need to do that is because this is a poor answer.  The correct approach is to make the query early (e.g. viewWillAppear) and reload within the completion block there.

Comment: The answer might be not so proficient but it helped, you can not say the answer is poor if it has been provided fast and helped requester.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the great optional syntax in swift to check if your array of values have loaded from parse

basically, you should have an optional array of PFObjects, so when the page loads while waiting for the data from parse, the array is nil. You check for a nil array in your table data source functions, and return zero for numberOfRows and nil for cellForRowAtIndexPath when the array is nil. Then check for a non nil array and use the count of the array for number of rows, and then pass the values to cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
This requires you to call tableView.reloadData() from the completion block of your parse call.

```
//pseudocode
func numberOfRowsInSection {
if let values = myArray as? [PFObject] { //this checks if the array is not nil
return values.count  //this returns the count

} else {
return 0     //if the array is nil tell your tableView there are zero rows to load
    }
```